# Deleting every 26th row of a matrix starting with row 8

Tags: matlab, matrix

Apologies if this is a relatively basic question - I'm still a bit new to programming, and particularly Matlab. I have a `4940x4940` square matrix that consists of `190` `26x26` matrices. Within each of these smaller matrices I want to delete every `8th` row and column (thus deleting row and column `8`, `34`, `60` ... of the overall matrix ).

What would the easiest way to do this be?

Thanks!

Comment: Though you have some answers, I would like to clarify something. You said you have smaller 26*26 matrices. So do you want to delete every 8th row of those smaller matrices, or every 8th row in overall matrix? That will be different, in the first case, you will delete row 8,16,24 in 1st smaller matrix again 8,16,24 in 2nd smaller matrix (that will be row number 34, 42, 48, ... in the whole matrix).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your title conflicts with the body of your question, but I will answer both.  By using the colon operator with a step value you can target specific rows to remove.  If you want to delete every 15th row of a matrix `x`, use the following code.

```
x(15:15:end,:) = [];
```

A similar process can be used to delete rows and columns at intervals of 26 starting at row or column 8.

```
x(8:26:end,:) = [];
x(:,8:26:end) = [];
```

I suggest reading up about the colon operator at [MathWorks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html).

Comment: +1, seems the answers are same! I'm gonna delete mine, good luck. You might also prepare a complete answer as @Parag S. Chandakkar suggested.